# PHP imagecopy removing png's color

Tags: php, copy, gd

I am trying to make a blackjack game that teaches card counting.  The visual component is important so I have a mock up of a deck of cards and some code that copies each dealt card's png file into a larger image to display the player and dealer's hands.  Unfortunately, every once in a while, my imagecopy is copying just a couple png's without color (in grayscale).  Here is the code for image creation, the rest of the code seems to be behaving flawlessly:

```
$cards = imagecreate( 360, 600 );

imagecopy( $cards, drawCard($dealershand[0]), 10, 10, 0, 0, 171, 254 );
imagecopy( $cards, @imagecreatefrompng("deckback.png"), 190, 10, 0, 0, 171, 254 );

imagecopy( $cards, drawCard($playershand[0]), 10, 336, 0, 0, 171, 254 );
imagecopy( $cards, drawCard($playershand[1]), 190, 336, 0, 0, 171, 254 );
```

If you need more code, just let me know and I can supply it but basically "drawCard" contains basically an if statement for red or black card and then a switch for the face value and outputs the `@imagecreatefrompng( carddealt )`, with card dealt file name generated inside as mocked up.  `$dealershand` and `$playershand` are just arrays of two cards, each with a face and suit value.

Thanks and sorry if this is already answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using imagecreatetruecolor instead of imagecreate.

Comment: Thank you Ronan but my question is then, and pardon the naivity of it if you don't mind: How do I use imagecreatetruecolor to create a image with white as the color?  Should I just make a white png file and use @imagecreatefrompng?

Comment: Thanks again, I ended up using @imagecreatefrompng and decided to go with a fake Blackjack table background but either way, abandoning imagecreate was the right thing to do.

Comment: I spent almost an hour until I found your answer. Thanks a lot.